# Simple Date Format for string

Tags: java, date, time, format, datetimeformatinfo

I have my current data as `2012-08-20T12:30:00+05:30`

```
  DateTime currentdata = "2012-08-20T12:30:00+05:30";
```

I am using

```
 String myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(currentdata);
```

I get `Cannot format given Object as a Date`

Any clues??

Comment: have you tried `Date` rather than `DateTime`?

Comment: I get DateTime in my request only..

Comment: can you convert with something like `Date dateOut = new Date(currentdata.getMillisecond());`, then use `dateOut` in your format call?

Comment: @oneofthelions Is the DateTime a joda.time class? If it is you can simply use something like this : `String myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(currentdata.toDate());`

Comment: @AxxAOsiris Yes it is joda.time. Thanks I shall try now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
String myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(currentdata.toDate());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String myDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(currentdata);
```

According to this line, currentdata may access String or Object.

```
  DateTime currentdata = "2012-08-2012:30:00+05:30";
```

According to this line, current data may be Object.This is error point.'format' method access Date object.Change your data type.If you don't want to change this, change your currentdata (2012-08-20T12:30:00+05:30) to (2012-08-2012 30:05:30). If you won't, illegal argument exception may be occured.